# Is it possible to link AJAX autocomplete to server-side event handler?

Tags: autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit, server-side, onselect

I am developing an ASP.NET Web Forms application in C#.

In my product reservation process I am using the ASP.NET **AJAX autocomplete extender** to retrieve **serial codes** of the products based on what the users digit.

Once a serial is selected I would like to **automatically** fill in also the TextBoxes for **ProductName and ProductPrice** to be retrieved from a **database**. That can be easily done on server-side by calling an event handler.

However it looks like there are **no server-side events** fired by the **AJAX autocomplete extender**. I found some **client-side** event but I have no clue on how to call a server-side function from Javascript.

I was suggested to use a new Javascript framework (**Node.js**) that interacts directly with the database but I have no experience with it.

Anybody can help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented search auto complete using jquery in asp.net application.Its prety much easy to implement and its performance is also great.You can link server side event handler too.
Complete detail is given here
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Comment: thanks for your answer. However my manager does not liek jQuery(don't ask me why). However it looks like there is no other solution. In the documentation is shown how it works with php not ASP.NET. May you please explain how to do it to call the web method feeding the suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You may use like this                                         <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $("#TextBoxId").autocomplete(AutoComplete.ashx'); }); </script>

Comment: I do not have the we method in a ashx file but inside the code. I know it is not a good practice but I am maintaining an existing application and the original design was this.